# Is $X_n$ a Markov chain? Write transition matrix.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

The number of task requests that arrive at a data center is a Poisson random variable, with number of average requests per day $\Lambda$. The calculations take a long time and the data center can resolve only one request per day. Furthermore space limits don't allow to hold more than N requests, other requests are rejected. Everyday only one request can be processed and if there are requests, processing begins the morning of everyday. The requests that arrive later don't be processed that day. 
$X_n$ is the number of requests that there are at the data center at the beginning of the day.

(a) Is $X_n$ a Markov chain? If it is, write its transition matrix.

(b) Is the Markov chain ergodic? Why?

(c) Write equations for stationary probabilities.

I stopped at point (a).
According to me it's a Markov chain, because if $X_{n+1}$ is the number of requests that there are at the data center at the beginning of the day $n+1$, so $X_{n+1}$ depended only by $X_n$.
My problem is write the matrix. I think that, Y$\sim$Poisson($\Lambda$) so $X_{n+1}=X_n+Y-1$. But I don't know if it is correct. And if it is correct, I don't know how go on.
Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, let $N=2$. So, assume that the center can keep only two requests. (The general solution can easily be given if it is understood for  $N=2$.

The following graph depicts the possible state transitions. Note that the state transitions take place overnight.

[image]

So, the data center has $3 $ states, $0$ denoting that there are no requests in the system (in the morning), $1$ meaning that there is only one request in the system (in the morning), and $2$ meaning that there are $2$ requests in the system (in the morning). Now, for example, if in the morning the system is in state $1$ and $4$ requests arrive during the day then the next state will be $2$ because the request already in the system gets resolved and only $2$ of the new arrivals will be stored...

Let's define the events $AZ, Z, B,C, A,D$:

- $AZ$: either no new request arrives or exactly one request arrives,
- $A$: exactly $1$ event arrives,
- $Z$: no requests arrive,
- $B$: exactly $2$ requests arrive,
- $C$: $2$ or more than $2$ requests arrive,
- $D$: $3$ or more than $3$ requests arrive.
- $E$: $1$ or more than $1$ requests arrive

Now, the state transition probabilities can be found. For example

$$p_{1,2}=P(C)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda^ke^{-\Lambda}}{k!}=$$
$$=1-e^{-\Lambda}-\Lambda e^{-\Lambda},$$
that is, the probability that the system jumps from state $1$ to state $2$ equals the probability of event $C$, the probability that $2$ or more requests arrive.

So, the state transition matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-\Lambda}+\Lambda e^{-\Lambda}&\frac{\Lambda^2e^{-\Lambda}}2&1-e^{-\Lambda}-\Lambda e^{-\Lambda}-\frac{\Lambda^2e^{-\Lambda}}2\\
e^{-\Lambda}&\Lambda e^{-\Lambda}&1-e^{-\Lambda}-\Lambda e^{-\Lambda}\\
0&e^{-\Lambda}&1-e^{-\Lambda}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then [Wiki explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity) how to check ergodicity based on the state transition matrix.

Also, the method of finding the stationary states [is given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Stationary_distribution_relation_to_eigenvectors_and_simplices).